# While loop page iteration for Meetup API not working

Tags: python, pandas, api, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to iterate through the pages of this Meetup API but I am receiving an error:

```
url = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?offset=1&format=json&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=100&radius=200.0&fields=&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=768bcf78d9c73937fcf2f5d41fe6070424f8d0e3'
while url:
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    url2 = data['meta'].get('next')
    data2 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['results'])
    print(data2)
```

However, when I write it as;

```
while url:
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(data)
url2 = data['meta'].get('next')
data2 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['results'])
```

It comes out as a list that keeps iterating it's self but I don't know if it's looping through the same page or not.

I also need to use this   `["offset"] += 1` somehow but fon't know where to place it

Comment: Im getting results from the first block of code (looks like `98               Python Programmers  
99     People Interested in SEO/SEM`). Can you maybe explain a little more what you are looking for or trying to do exactly?

Comment: Hi @NathanBlaine, That is the result but I believe that's only one page so it might be looping over that same page unfortunately. I'm trying to iterate through the API's url pages (the page changes at Offset +-1 within the url) and then put all of it into a pandas Dataframe.

Comment: Hope the sig and sig_id parameters in url are not private keys.

Comment: the while loop will run indefinitely, do you know how many pages do you want?

Comment: @iamkhush the sig and sig_id are private to each person I believe but not difficult to get (if you have a meetup login you're assigned one automatically). Also, yes I need 590 pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is also a parameter `page` that you can use in your api call.

```
page = 1
url = '<base_url>&page=%d'
while page < 590:
  new_url = url % page
  # fetch new_url and do your magic
  ....
  page += 1
```

Comment: Getting this error; 

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` 

when I put that code in 

`page = 1
url = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?offset=590&format=json&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=100&radius=200.0&fields=&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=768bcf78d9c73937fcf2f5d41fe6070424f8d0e3'

while page < 590:
    new_url = url % page
    
    page += 1 `






I've tried to change the `page` for `offset` instead but getting errors

Comment: You need to add `&page=%d` at the end of the url.